# Does the viewstate or WebResource.axd paths ever change if the content does not?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have inherited a website for which I do not have the source code. All the pages are precompiled. I have been tasked to display a notice on the login page with our intent to shut down the site forever.

*This can be a total hack, as long as it works, since the website is going away anyway.*

Since I don't have the source, my thought was to create a copy of the rendered html of the login page and save it to a static html with the notice included on it and then change the default page in IIS to point to this new page. I did a preliminary test and it seems to be working.

My concern is that it might stop working if the ASP.NET will expect a ViewState or WebResource.axd querystring parameter that is different than the ones I hard-coded in the static page.

Is this a workable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebResource.axd:

[`AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrl`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Handlers/AssemblyResourceLoader.cs#114694f2eb85728b#references) is a method which is responsible for `WebResource.axd` URL generation.

To be precise [`CreateWebResourceCacheKey`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Handlers/AssemblyResourceLoader.cs#3b0d308f4169c102#references) method is used for URL generation for custom resources and there are predefined set of URLs for built-in libraries (`WebForms.js`, `WebUIValidation.js`, `SmartNav.htm`, `SmartNav.js`).

```
private static int CreateWebResourceUrlCacheKey(Assembly assembly, string resourceName,
            bool htmlEncoded, bool forSubstitution, bool enableCdn, bool debuggingEnabled, bool secureConnection) {
    int hashCode = HashCodeCombiner.CombineHashCodes(
        assembly.GetHashCode(),
        resourceName.GetHashCode(),
        htmlEncoded.GetHashCode(),
        forSubstitution.GetHashCode(),
        enableCdn.GetHashCode());
    return HashCodeCombiner.CombineHashCodes(hashCode,
        debuggingEnabled.GetHashCode(),
        secureConnection.GetHashCode());
}
```

As you can see the URL generation is deterministic and based on hash codes. As long as you are not changing framework version where hash calculation algorithm could be different you are safe to use hardcoded URLS.

View state:

The short answer is - you cannot hardcode view state value if you expect users to interact with application. I would recommend to read [View State and Security Implications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic12) section of [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) article. It explains a bit about `MAC (Machine Authentication Check)` and `ViewStateUserKey` values which are used to make view state more secure making it almost impossible to fake its values.

---

So, if you are dependent on view state I would recommend to create a custom `HttpModule` (see [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx)), put the resulting assembly to the app `bin` folder and then register it in `web.config`. The new module would be responsible for notice html generation that would be injected to the resulting document.

Comment: I decoded the ViewState and there is nothing in there that will change or that is per user. Also, if any interaction is required, like if the user submits a wrong password, the original login page gets sent down with the updated ViewState. As long as the users saw the notice initially, this would be acceptable. Given these conditions, can you think of any reason why I couldn't proceed with my plan? Is there anything else that would cause the ViewState to become invalid?

Comment: @adam0101 Well, I think everything should be fine then. But anyways it is a hacky way to accomplish the task, my bet would be to use `HttpModule`, just because it is more predictable thing :)